# I can't open mpv player in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

mpv: error while loading shared libraries: libgbm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

everything is from Ubuntu's repository, the 3rd party ppa doesn't work either.

I directly upgrade it from 14.04 to 16.04

Comment: Is the libgbm1 package installed?

Comment: Yes, libgbm1 is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-lts-transitional/+bug/1572855) and I have found the answer.

```
sudo dpkg-divert --remove /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1.0.0
sudo dpkg-divert --remove /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgbm1
```

Comment: FWIW, this also fixed problems with running Rednotebook on 16.04.

Comment: For me this was the issue: mpv: _error while loading shared libraries: liblua5.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory_
 So I ran this to fix it:  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall liblua5.2-0`

Answer (score 1):

The following solution posted as a comment by [Noki](https://askubuntu.com/users/198231/noki) worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libula5.2-0
```

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04 and had this problem for months.

Comment: @Thomas: Since the answer refers to a comment and not an answer itself, I'd prefer to keep it.